# Rails validation for image link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i am creating a rails application and i wanna user to be able to enter link for his/her profile picture from Facebook or any external site .

how to be sure this link is for image??
how to create a validation for that ??

Answer (score 1):

Use this validation in model.

```
validates_format_of :image, :with => %r{\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$}i, :message => "Use a real image"
```

Please be aware that this would only validate that the filename would end in a specific string.

Use [fastimage](https://github.com/sdsykes/fastimage) to get type and size of images by quickly fetching.
eg.

```
FastImage.type("http://stephensykes.com/images/pngimage")
```

returns .png

Comment: This will not work for all images. All this does is check for whether it's a gif, jpeg or png.
My profile picture for example looks like this: `https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/111234679_108812312312393793_9158913373854112341_n.jpg?oh=a458711ffbcdd645f3321412d07393ee7&oe=1234123`.
Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: i saw this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645584/rails-image-url-validation) and i doesn't work for my situation

Comment: @PhilM. Added a gem to do real time image validation, thanks.

Comment: @Hassan Split your url till you get a .jpg, then use fastimage to fetch and see if it's real.
Original Fb link : https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/asas.jpg?asas....

After split : https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofi/3373854112341_n.jpg

Use : string.split(".jpg")

Comment: img.rb:3: unknown regexp options - ctt
img.rb:3: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
...xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtf1/v/t1.0-9/10417722_713578532034023_...
...